# Concurrent use of WeakReference<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, weak-references

The documentation for [WeakReference<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738(v=vs.110).aspx) has the common boilerplate for thread-safety:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe**.

However, I'm wondering whether it is indeed safe to use instance members of WeakReference<T> anyway?

In particular, I'm wondering whether is is safe to allow concurrent access to something like this:

```
class MyRef<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<Task<T>> _fetcher;
    private readonly WeakReference<T> _wref;

    public MyRef(Func<Task<T>> fetcher, T target = null)
    {
        _fetcher = fetcher;
        _wref = new WeakReference<T>(target);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetTargetAsync()
    {
        T target;

        if (!_wref.TryGetTarget(out target))
        {
            target = await _fetcher();
            _wref.SetTarget(target);
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Both [`TryGetTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712926(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SetTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737195(v=vs.110).aspx) are used here, possibly invoked concurrently by multiple threads.

Both of them are invoking the private external `Target` property implemented by native code. ([Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/weakreferenceoft.cs,82))

I'd like to know whether the native implementation really isn't safe for concurrent access before I start protecting code like the one above with synchronization locks.

---

**What would count as *safe* to me here?**

Simply, if I could use the code above without causing any unexpected exception or access violation due to concurrent invocations of the two methods.

More explicitly:

- `TryGetTarget` would either return `true` and give me a non-null reference; or `false`. No exceptions.
- `SetTarget` would not cause any exception.

Comment: Define what you mean by "safe here". "Thread safety" is not a blanket concept that is universally agreed upon. It is only safe *for you* if it does *what you expect*. What would you want or expect it to do?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please see my recent edit for a clarification.

Comment: The documentation of [`WeakReference<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738(v=vs.110).aspx) has this at the bottom: "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**" *(my emphasis)* So no, you cannot guarantee it won't crash.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I'm aware of that. And that's why I put a quote of that at the very top of this question. I'm wondering about the implementation details.

Comment: You shouldn't. It is documented to be unsafe, the implementation is irrelevant. It may be safe right now, it may not safe after the next .NET hotfix or major release.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's a good and valid point. However, I'm still interested of the details. *Why* wouldn't it be safe right now, or *why* is it safe right now?

Comment: By looking in coreclr at [`SetTarget`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/weakreferencenative.cpp#L793) it seems to be protected by a `AcquireWeakHandleSpinLock`... a lock of some type. So it is probably thread safe. Where "probably" is more "probably this evening I'll eat meat" than "probably tomorrow the sun will still be there" :-)

Comment: @xanatos Ah, thank you! I tried to find that source code without success.

Comment: The same for [`GetWeakReferenceTarget`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/weakreferencenative.cpp#L576) (used internally by the getter of `Target` that is then used by the `TryGetTarget`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the [ecallist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L2111) we can see that the internal methods of `WeakTarget`/`WeakTarget<T>` are implemented in the `WeakReferenceNative`/`WeakReferenceOfTNative` classes. Looking at their  [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/weakreferencenative.cpp) we can see that there is an `AcquireWeakHandleSpinLock` both in the [`SetTarget`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/weakreferencenative.cpp#L808) (used by the `Target` setter) and in the [`GetWeakReferenceTarget`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/weakreferencenative.cpp#L576), used by the `Target` getter and by the `TryGetTarget`.

So probably the whole `Target`/`TryGetTarget` are thread safe (**in the sense that they won't corrupt internal structures of .NET**), but you will need a better programmer than me to check that they really are :-)

Clearly using the `Target`/`TryGetTarget` won't make the targetted object thread safe! That is another problem!

Comment: Note that this answer refers to the .NET Core implementation, and not the "old" .NET in the case you are still using ASP.NET.